# Надо сделать на PHP кнопку которая будет отключать картинки

Tags: php, изображения

Как сделать кнопку/скрипт чтобы отключать картинки на сайте?

Необходимо адаптировать сайт для слабовидящих, и одним из требований является кнопка отключения изображений.

Может, есть функция какая-то?

Comment: На PHP кнопку сделать нельзя, можно при помощи html/js, а через PHP вывести ее. Т.е. для начала необходимо сначала реализовать это самому на js/html.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам лучше использовать html и CSS вот пример

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <head> 
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" /> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Test</title> <style type="text/css"> .hidden { display: none; } </style> </head> 
<body> <form> <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';" /> 
</form> <img id="hidden" class="hidden" src="foo.png" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой функции нет. Это все делается в совокупности (PHP+HTML+JavaScript). Сделай на сайте кнопку, при нажатии на которую на клиентскую машину устанавливается cookie, например такая: noimage=1. Дальше строй алгоритм с учетом этой cookie. Есть cookie - не показываем картинки, а если такой cookie нет - показываем.

```
...
if ( hasCookieNoImage ) {
    //...without images...
} else {
    //...with images...
}
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. а есть кусочек кода, который сразу не грузит картинки? Т,Е, чел зашел на сайт и картинок нет .

Comment: Нет, такого кода у меня нет. Но ты можешь переделать мой алгоритм. Пусть PHP проверяет есть ли например cookie showimage=1, и если нет - то не показывать картинки, а если есть - то показывать. Таким образом изначально человек не видит картинки, а вот если он нажмет на кнопку "Показывать картинки" и она положит клиенту cookie, то картинки появятся. Как-то так....

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

адаптация сайта для людей с ограниченными возможностями — это не «добавление пары-тройки кнопок, вызывающих хитрые функции».

это комплексный процесс, которым стоит заниматься с самого начала разработки — ведь результатом его будет сайт, который (скорее всего) будет более удобен для использования **всеми** людьми.

полезные ссылки:

- [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)
- [перевод Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0](http://wcag.ru/guidelines/wcag20.html)
- [краткое изложение концепций, изложенных в руководстве](http://habrahabr.ru/company/netcat/blog/165697/)

Comment: Какая пара-тройка кнопок?? С чего вы взяли что я добавляю пару-тройку хитрых функций? У  меня конкретный вопрос. Ссылки - прелесть! К чему только?

Comment: @Samol, возможно, сайт, который вы адаптируете, с самого начала разрабатывался без учёта «правил хорошего тона», поэтому, вполне вероятно, **в вашем случае** действительно проще добавить какие-то «заплаты и надстройки». /// **но** этот ваш вопрос останется в базе знаний сайта [ru.so], и, возможно, мой ответ поможет кому-то другому сэкономить время и усилия — **сразу** делать сайт «по-правильному», а не переделывать потом под «вновь возникшие требования».

Answer (score 0):

На стороне сервера, получается, придется каждый раз искать в контенте теги изображений, и прогоняя через условия показывать \ не показывать изображения. 
Зачем? Если можно всю лишнюю работу свесить на клиента? 
Для начала, как уже было сказано, вешаете куку, и на стороне клиента уже проверяете,  и если нужно удаляете изображения

Comment: Да, так и надо делать.